# Create rule in Hyperon studio

Tags: hyperon

We are exploring Hyperon for certain use cases and trying to create one basic rule using Hyoeron Studio as per below –

A > 12
AND B/C >= 0.5
AND D IS TRUE
AND E IN ('Val1',’Val2')
AND F IS NOT 45

As per documentation given in website, we followed below steps

1. Created Context – (Example ; Mer)
2. Created attributes of the context – (A, B, C, D, E)
3. Created parameter as rule (for example, we named “Validate Data”)
4. Created column names under parameter and then selected attributes (from step 2) as value source
5. In decision table under the parameter, entered the combinations to setup the Rule

Queries –

1. Is this the right approach of setting up the rule? Or is there any other way/screen in which rule can be setup easily?
2. If there is any mathematical operations(for e.g. B/C), groovy function / custom code in business application is the only way which means’ not possible through UI in studio?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes this is the right approach, each column you should treat as part of the logical expression and "AND" between them. Matchers can be used to find the result in range for example 12 - * and matcher between/ie will replace "A > 12"
2. you need to do a little trick here. You must write a small function dividing B over C and returns the value. Then you use that function as the input source for the column in Hyperon's parameter instead of the direct reference to the context.